# Android email validation vs Firebase email validation

Tags: android, validation, firebase, firebase-authentication

**Is there any way to use Firebase  email validation without performing credentials update and listening for failures? Something along the lines of `FirebaseAuth.validateEmail(someEmail)` ?**

In Android it is possible to check for valid input email using :

`android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(someEmail).matches();`

However this accepts emails finishing with top level domain being one character long, eg. `test@email.c`

Such emails however, are invalid for Firebase and will throw the following exception if used:

`com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occured. [ INVALID_EMAIL ]`

Is there a way of marking an input field invalid if user enters a firebase-invalid email address?

Answer (score 0):

After I do some research, `INVALID_EMAIL` seems to have two reasons. One is invalid format which can be checked the Android method. The other one is the Email is not signed up. I think you are facing the second case since `test@email.c` is valid in Email format (Although the domain doesn't exists).

Therefore, I do not think there is a `FirebaseAuth.validateEmail(someEmail)` method but the authentication method itself is to validate the Email. It throws exception if it is invalid, so you can use `try` and `catch` to handle the invalid case.

Comment: How do you mean *`test@email.c` is a valid Email format*? Generally speaking or valid for Firebase? When attempting to use it to sign in or update email credentials Firebase returns with `INVALID_EMAIL`. Also, when you refer to *the authentication method itself*, which function do you have in mind?